# Change selected images for a UITabBarController with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to create a tabbed application for iPhone. I'm trying to create the iOS 7 style tabbar with lined icons when a item in unselected and filled icons when a item is selected.

I've read a few solutions including the one with setfinishedselectedimage, but that's deprecated since iOS 7.

I've also tried to use the following code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"motivations"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"/Tabbar/home_line.png"]];
self.tabBarItem = tabBarItem;
}
```

But that's not doing anything at all.

I'm pretty new with objective-c and object oriented programming. I hope there's someone who can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 7 the best way ti initialize a tabbar item is:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
UIImage *myImageSel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageSel.png"];

myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
myImageSel = [myImageSel imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.myViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyTabbariitem" image:myImage selectedImage:myImageSel];
```

Comment: I added this to the viewcontroller files. I've deselected the tabbarimage in the interface builder. But the title isn't showing up, and the image is also not showing up.

Comment: I've solved the problem. I had to remove the myViewController part in the last line of code! Thanks!